# If the price of coffee is raised by 25%, by what percentage a householder must reduce his consumption of coffee so as not increase his expenditure?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If the price of coffee is raised by 25%, by what percentage a householder must reduce his consumption of coffee so as not increase his expenditure?

Price of the coffee is $x $  Expenditure is $y$   Consumption will be $xy$
Increased price of coffee is $1.25x$   Expenditure is y  consumption will be $1.25xy$

Now what to do next?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

If $p$ is the old price and $q$ is the old consumption, the new consumption $x$ must be such that:
$$
1.25p \cdot x=p\cdot q
$$

so: $x=...$

---

the percentage variation of consumption is:
$$
\Delta( q)\% =\frac{x-q}{q} \cdot 100=\left(\frac{x}{q}-1  \right)\cdot 100
$$

with ( from the previous equation)

$$x=\frac{q}{1.25}$$

can you do this?

Comment: x=1.25 ....
.25p/p*100 is the right answer? @Emilio

Comment: How do I calculate the decrease percentage? @EmilioNovati

Comment: I've added to my answer.

Comment: I didn't understand

Answer (score 0):

Price Proportional to .......1/ Consumption

If Price Increases, Consumption Decreases.

The Decrement % in Consumption is :

X / (100 + X) * 100

Where X = Percentage Increment in Price.

So, 25 / (100 + 25) * 100 = 20 %

20% Less Consumption.

Answer (score -1):

```
  Price Consumption Expenditure
```

OLD   10     10           100
 NEW   12.5   X            100

Consumption (X)= 100/12.5=4

Change = 10-4/10*100= 60%

Answer (score -2):

Since exp. Constant

P1C1=P2C2

P1C1=5/4P1C1

C1/C2=5/4

(C1-C2)*100/C1%=1/5*100%=20%